# Unable to split audio using easy_audio_trimmer

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, ffmpeg, flutter-dependencies

can we use the easy_audio_trimmer package to split an audio? I tried using the ffmpeg but it is conflicting with the above package and not work.

I tried splitting  by using these functions and it gave an error at the FlutterFFmpeg() method and i cant find an alternative also the duration(filePath) in the command final durationResult = await flutterSound.duration(filePath); shows an error

```
Future<void> _splitAudio() async {
    setState(() {
      _progressVisibility = true;
    });

    // Get the application documents directory
    final appDocumentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // Get the input audio file path
    final inputAudioPath = widget.file.path;

    // Get the output file names for the two parts
    final outputFileName1 = 'split_audio_part1.mp3';
    final outputFileName2 = 'split_audio_part2.mp3';

    // Get the output file paths for the two parts
    final outputPath1 = '${appDocumentsDirectory.path}/$outputFileName1';
    final outputPath2 = '${appDocumentsDirectory.path}/$outputFileName2';

    // Calculate the duration of the original audio
    final originalDuration = await _getAudioDuration(inputAudioPath);

    // Calculate the durations of the two parts
    final part1Duration = _startValue;
    final part2Duration = originalDuration - _endValue;

    // Construct the FFmpeg command to split the audio
    final ffmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
    final splitCommand = '-i $inputAudioPath -ss 0 -t $part1Duration -c copy $outputPath1 -ss $_endValue -t $part2Duration -c copy $outputPath2';

    try {
      // Execute the FFmpeg command to split the audio
      final int result = await ffmpeg.execute(splitCommand);

      if (result == 0) {
        setState(() {
          _progressVisibility = false;
        });
        debugPrint('Audio split successfully.');
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _progressVisibility = false;
        });
        debugPrint('Failed to split audio.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _progressVisibility = false;
      });
      debugPrint('Error while splitting audio: $error');
    }
  }

  Future<int> _getAudioDuration(String filePath) async {
    final flutterSound = FlutterSound();
    final durationResult = await flutterSound.duration(filePath);
    return durationResult.inMilliseconds;
  }
```

Dependencies

```
 path_provider: ^2.0.15
  ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^5.1.0
  audioplayers: ^4.1.0
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
```